# MySQL use DELETE FROM to remove duplicates rows

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-delete, self-join

I'm learning MySQL and today I tried to solve an MySQL question on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/delete-duplicate-emails/solution/

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
| 3  | john@example.com |
+----+------------------+
Id is the primary key column for this table.
```

The basic idea is to remove duplicate rows from the table and only keep the one with the smallest Id. Expect results:

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
+----+------------------+
```

The solution is

```
DELETE p1 FROM Person p1,Person p2 
WHERE
p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id
```

And I tried a second test case myself:

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
| 3  | john@example.com |
| 4  | john@example.com |
+----+------------------+
```

The output is:

```
+----+------------------+
| Id | Email            |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | john@example.com |
| 2  | bob@example.com  |
+----+------------------+
```

I don't understand why the condition p1.Id > p2.Id only keeps the row with the smallest id because I  think it only rules out the smaller one, it wouldn't apply to
the case where there were more than 2 duplicates, right？ But as the second test case shows, it indeed works.
I think it's because of the syntax of

```
DELETE Table1
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

How does this work exactly? Can someone gives me an explanation here, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is a very bad way of implementing this code.  But I guess you get what you pay for.

Second, simply run the query as a `select`:

```
SELECT p1.*, p2.*
FROM Person p1 JOIN
     Person p2 
     ON p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id;
```

(Note that I've rewritten the logic as a `JOIN`.  You should *always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax, but the two methods are functionally equivalent.)

On your second example, the results of this query are:

```
table1 email     table1 id    table2 id
john@example.com.    2            1
john@example.com.    3            1
john@example.com.    3            2
```

What is notable is that id = 1 is never in the second column -- and that is the column that determines which ids are deleted.  In other words, all but the smallest id for each email get deleted because there is a smaller `id`.

This also hints at why this is a really bad solution.  MySQL has to deal with two rows for `id = 3`.  Perhaps it attempts to delete both.  Perhaps it has to just deal with extra data.  Either way, there is extra work.  And the more rows with the same email in the data the more extra duplicates are created.

An alternative method, such as:

```
delete p
    from person p join
         (select email, min(id) as min_id
          from person p2
          group by email
         ) p2
         on p.email = p2.email and p.id > p2.min_id;
```

Does not have this problem and, in my opinion, the intent is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I find the reason myself. The DELETE here doesn't work exactly the same as a normal DELETE statement

```
DELETE
FROM TABLE
WHERE conditions
```

But rather

```
DELETE T1, T2
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.key = T2.key
WHERE condition;
```

It's often called `MySQL DELETE JOIN statement`, and this is how it works.

For more details https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-join/

Comment: Omit the first T2 from your query.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to delete
Try changing your query to

```
DELETE p2 FROM Person p1,Person p2 
  WHERE
p1.Email = p2.Email AND p1.Id > p2.Id
```

and you will see a different result

Answer (score 0):

If you try the SELECT statement for that (*remove the WHERE p1 > p2 for the meantime*)

```
    SELECT p1.*, p2.*, CASE WHEN p1.Id > p2.Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM Person p1,Person p2 
    WHERE p1.Email = p2.Email
```

You can check the value of the condition statement. IDs 3 and 4 satisfy the condition, thus, they will be deleted in the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9s8.png)

I suggest you do the same for UPDATE and INSERT operation with JOIN when you're debugging your script to see how the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend phrasing the query like this:

```
delete t
from mytable t
inner join (select email, min(id) as min_id from mytable group by email) t1
    on t.email = t1.email and t.id > t1.min_id
```

This joins the self-table against an aggregation query that returns the minimum `id` per `email`. Why I am suggesting this is that each row matched only once, as opposed to the approach that self-joins without aggregation, that ends up deleting the same row multiple times if there a given email has more than 2 duplicates. In that regard, the above query is more efficient, and somehow safer.